# How to use mod rewrite to serve child site off of parent

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to configure Apache with a rewrite rule such that a "parent" site can point to a "child" site. The directory structure I'm trying to get to work looks like this:

```
parent/
  index.html
  children/        # Logically this should point to container/000
    .htaccess
    some-other-file.html

container/
  000/
    childA/
      index.html
```

I want any requests under `parent/children` which don't exist to be served from another directory which exists somewhere else on disk.  In the example here that directory is `container/000`.

I currently have this rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file of the parent site.

```
#
# parent/children/.htaccess
#
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /container/000/$1
```

This works for *files* within `ChildA`, as well as the `ChildA` directory if it ends with a slash.  However if I leave the slash off of the child, I get a 301 redirect with the *rewritten path*, which is not what I want.

Example:

```
mysite.com/parent/children/childA/index.html  # Works fine
mysite.com/parent/children/childA/            # Also works, serves index

# This doesn't do what I want
mysite.com/parent/children/childA
```

The last example serves the correct page but I get a 301 redirect to `mysite.com/container/000/childA/`.  What I want is a redirect to `mysite.com/parent/children/childA/`, which is the original request but with a slash.

How can I achieve that?

I tried adding the `AllowNoSlash` rewrite option but that did not help.  I have seen other examples of adding a missing slash to a directory using a rewrite rule, but those work on the assumption that the request maps to an existing directory... in my case the requested directory doesn't exist.

## EDIT

The first two answers didn't help. I was still getting a 301 redirect to a path under the container directory.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I also have a **VirtualHost** with a **VirtualDocumentRoot**.  I'm adding the server configuration and expanding on the example above.

### server configuration

```
<Directory /sites>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /sites/container>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /container /sites/container

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /sites/%-2.1/%-2.2/%-2.0.%-1/
</VirtualHost>
```

### file layout

```
sites
├── container
│   ├── 000
│   │   └── childA
│   │       └── index.html
│   └── .htaccess
└── p
    └── a
        └── parent.com
            ├── children
            │   ├── .htaccess
            │   └── index.html
            └── index.html
```

### URLs

```
parent.com/children/childA/index.html  # Works fine
parent.com/children/childA/            # Also works, serves index

# This gives me a 301 redirect to /container/000/childA/
parent.com/children/childA
```

The suggestion from @anubhava looks promising but the first rewrite rule fails to match.

If I enter `parent.com/children/childA` in my browser I get a 301 redirect to `parent.com/container/000/childA/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trailing slash is added by `mod_dir` module after `mod_rewrite` if current REQUEST_URI is a directory.

To fix this you can have your rules like this:

```
# parent/children/.htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash to rewritten directories
RewriteCond /sites/container/000/$1/ -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /container/000/$1
```

Comment: This didn't work. I get a 301 redirect to `mysite.com/container-000/childA/`. I also have a VirtualHost defined, I wonder if that is contributing to the problem.

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser? Can you test in Chrome dev tool to see what redirects you get.

Comment: I updated my question with some more details.  The first RewriteRule you suggested fails to match... would this be related to the virtual document root?

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` doesn't get set for `VirtualDocumentRoot` due to a bug in Apache.  Replace `RewriteCond` line with `RewriteCond /sites/container/000/$1/ -d`

Answer (score 1):

This should be on by default but try adding this to the top of your .htaccess file.

```
DirectorySlash On
```

I also would add the trailing slash to my rule as well to make it optional. And make sure to use the `L` flag to tell it to stop processing after a match.

```
#
# parent/children/.htaccess
#
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /container/000/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This didn't work. I get a 301 redirect to `mysite.com/container-000/childA/`.  I also have a VirtualHost defined, I wonder if that is contributing to the problem.